# Relevant materials on how to create a new web application that have community site and integrate with AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, community

I need to implement a simple web application using SharePoint 2013 server, which mainly contains the following :-

1. A new intranet web application , that uses our company active directory to authenticate users.
2. Inside the intranet I need to have a Community site, that allows users to add discussion, reply to discussion, like, etc.
3. Inside the intranet web application, I want to have general calendar that show predefined public holidays and events .
4. And these calendar events should only be created by site collection administrator, and can be viewed by users.
5. Optional. To be able to have multiple calendars , one which shows public holiday for US , other which shows public holiday for Canada, etc. and users can select certain calendar and view its events and holidays.

Can anyone advice on some materials or help on how to achieve this ?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

I will suggest you to read some basic book on SharePoint functionality.. These are all Out of the box features and you can easily customize them for your needs..

Books Suggestions:
[How to Do Everything Microsoft SharePoint 2013](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007180983X)
[Getting Started With SharePoint 2013](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AV0K806)
[Beginning SharePoint 2013: Building Business Solutions (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118495896)

For more in-depth knowledge about Administration of SharePoint:
[SharePoint 2013 - First Look for Power Users](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/098848160X)